# Как сделать кнопку назад ? Машина состояний aiogram Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Есть вот такой код, не работает кнопка назад, делал по примеру из официальной документации [aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html?highlight=state%3D)

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

class AdminChannel(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    id = State()
    link = State()

#/admin
@dp.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message('5004824939', 'Админ панель:', reply_markup=AdminPanel)

#Инлайн 'Добавить канал'
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_check(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback_query.data == 'add_chennel':
        await AdminChannel.name.set()
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Напишите имя канала:', reply_markup=backMenu)

#Состояние 'Добавление канала'
@dp.message_handler(state=AdminChannel.name)
async def add_name_channel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await AdminChannel.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Укажите id канала:', reply_markup=backMenu)

@dp.message_handler(state=AdminChannel.id)
async def add_id_channel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['id'] = message.text
    await AdminChannel.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Укажите ссылку на канал:', reply_markup=backMenu)

@dp.message_handler(state=AdminChannel.link)
async def add_link_channel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['link'] = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data['name'], data['id'], data['link'])
    await state.finish()

#Обработка кнопки 'Назад'
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='Назад')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Назад', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Cancelled.', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


'''keyboard'''
#Назад
btnBack = KeyboardButton('Назад')
backMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(btnBack)

#admin
inBtnAdminDownload = InlineKeyboardButton('Загрузить фильм', callback_data='download_movie')
inBtnAdminAddChannel = InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить канал', callback_data='add_chennel')
AdminPanel = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1).add(inBtnAdminDownload,inBtnAdminAddChannel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодиться.
Кнопка "Назад" должна быть прописана сразу после класса AdminChannel